# Diagonalizing a 3x3 matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Prove that matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, find the bases for the eigenspaces, the diagonalizing matrix $P$, and compute $P^{-1} A P$ where 
$A= \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 2 & 0 & 3 \\
      0 & 3 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 3  \end{array}\right).$

Comment: So what have you done?

Comment: I've got the that one of the eigenvalues is 1 that's all I could get so far.

Comment: No, 1 is not an eigenvalue. You have an upper triangular matrix, so the eigenvalues are on the main diagonal.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of algebraic and geometric multiplicities? Remember, a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it is not [defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix). A non-defective matrix will have equal algebraic and geometric multiplicities for each eigenvalue.

Comment: I'm new to this so I'm not sure how it works. The eigenvalues to this matrix is 2 and 3 since they're on the diagonal?

Comment: Yes. $\det(A-\lambda I)=(2-\lambda)(3-\lambda)^2$, so 2 has multiplicity 1 and 3 has multiplicity 2. ... Now, find a basis for each eigenspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix is diagonalizable if it is similar to a diagonal matrix. So in order to prove this matrix is diagonalizable, why don't we make it similar to a diagonal matrix.

As it is upper triangular, we can just read the eigenvalues off of the diagonal (to convince yourself of this, try finding $det(A-\lambda I)$ for any diagonal A or remember that finding the determinant of a diagonal matrix is just summing the diagonal entries):
$\lambda=2,3$.

Then finding the eigenvectors, we look at the null space of $A-I\lambda$ for the two eigenvalues.

For $\lambda=2$, we find the nullspace of
$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&3\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$, which eyeballing we can see is the vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

or $\lambda=3$, we find the nullspace of
$\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&3\\0&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ which we can eyeball one easily as $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Then we need one more for this matrix to be diagonalizable, and fortunately this one is pretty clear too we need the first input in row 1 to sum with the third input to 0, 
$\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ fits the bill.

Now we have put the eigenvectors together to get our $P=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ which we can invert and plug into the formula $PDP^{-1}=A$, with D the matrix with eigenvalues on the diagonal,

$D=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&3 \end{bmatrix}$
I leave it to you to compute $P^{-1}$ and multiply by the appropriate values to go from
$PDP^{-1}=A$ to $P^{-1}AP=D$

Comment: You need to fix $D$; it's not diagonal.

Comment: oops forgot to fix that! thanks

Comment: Just an additional question: Is it true that the diagoalizing matrix is always orthogonal

Comment: @BhaskarPandey no, it isnt in this answer in fact

Comment: @qbert Thanks for the info !

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial is $ \text{det}(A−λI)=(2−λ)(3−λ)^2$ so the eigenvalues of your matrix are $2$ and $ 3$. Therefore $2$ is an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $1,$ and $3$ is an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $2$. Recall the geometric multiplicity can also be described as the dimension of the nullspace of $A-λI$.

So for $λ = 2$ we have $A-λI = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 
      0 & 0 & 3 \\
      0 & 1 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 1  \end{array}\right)$ so the null space has dimension $1.$ Thus the geometric multiplicity for $λ = 2$ is $1$.

Now for $λ = 3$ we have $A-λI = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} 
      -1 & 0 & 3 \\
      0 & 0 & 0 \\
      0 & 0 & 0  \end{array}\right)$ so the null space has dimension $2.$ Thus the geometric multiplicity for $λ = 3$ is $2$.

Because the algebraic multiplicities equal the geometric multiplicities for all the eigenvalues, by definition the matrix is non-defective and hence diagonalizable.

For a good explanation of diagonalizability see Chapter 24 of "Numerical Linear Algebra" by Trefethen and Bau.