# Find a matrix $P$ that diagonalizes

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

$$
 A=
 \begin{bmatrix}
  3 & -2 & 0 \\
  -2 & 3 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 5 \
 \end{bmatrix}
 $$
I can find the eigenvalues is $\lambda = 1$ and $\lambda = 5$ but when I apply them into $A$, I can't find the eigenvectors, can you help me with this part ?

Comment: you have to consider and solve $(A-\lambda I)x=0$

Comment: $(1,1,0)$; $(0,0,1)$; $(1,-1,0)$.

Comment: yes i did but everything I can find is $x_1 = x_2$ and $x_3 = 0$

Comment: You should find three distinct eigenvectors, since A is symmetric.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can you show me how ?

Comment: @HàNhị $x_1=x_2$ and $x_3=0$ is precisely an eigenvector (1,1,0), now you have to find teh other 2

Comment: @HàNhị take also a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764857/diagonalizing-a-3x3-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @gimusi got it, thank you so much !

Comment: @HàNhị Well done! You're welcome, Bye.

Answer (score 0):

for the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$:
$A(x,y,z)^t=(x,y,z)^t$ is equivalent to
$$3x-2y=x$$
$$-2x+3y=y$$
$$5z=z$$
which defines the subspace $Sp\{(1,1,0)\}$. So an eigenvector for $\lambda=1$ is $(1,1,0)$. can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

If you solve the system $A.\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}\right)=5\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{smallmatrix}$, you will get a $2$-dimensional space. An obvious element of that space is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and another (less obvious) one is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. These two are linearly independent. Finally, $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$. So, if you define$$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$(the columns are the eigenvectors), then$$P^{-1}.A.P=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&5&0\\0&0&5\end{pmatrix}.$$